# Align values in an INI file generated using ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

Below is the INI file i am generating using the ConfigParser:

```
[Global]
no_of_games =
superconf =
```

I am trying to generate an INI file with the "=" aligned uniformly as below, how could i achieve this, is there a way in the config parser to align the "=" at same position for all records ?

```
[Global]
no_of_games   =
superconf     =
```

Comment: This might get confusing, or hard to read if there are entries with names' length varying a lot.

Comment: You can subclass `ConfigParser` and provide your own `write` method but that's about it.  You can use your own writer just fine also, but that doesn't involve `ConfigParser`.  Does your solution *need* to involve `ConfigParser`?  If not, I might remove that from the title since it suggests how you think you need to do something, and not what you actually need to do.

BTW writing your own serializer for ini files is not too hard.  I usually do it anyways since `ConfigParser` does not preserve comments when writing and I usually find it preferable to preserve them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to design a converter to save another ini file.
But I think it's not a good idea.

Such like:

```
text = row
if row.find('=') > 0:
    data = row.split('=')
    var, val = data[0], data[1]
    text = "{0:<15} = {1:<15}\n".format(var, val.strip())
```